# Is there a way to pass data between two same level component in Angular using @Input?

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components, angular-decorator

[Folder structure of the project (for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9tPh.png)

**dynamic-container.component.html**

```
<h1>Dynamic component in angular</h1>
<ul>
    <li (click)="createComponent(productNames.mobile)">Mobile</li>
    <li (click)="createComponent(productNames.laptop)">Laptop</li>
    <li (click)="createComponent(productNames.watch)">Watch</li>
    <li (click)="createComponent(productNames.burger)">Burger</li>
    <li (click)="createComponent(productNames.ovan)">Ovan</li>
</ul>

<div class="display black-border">
    <ng-container #container></ng-container>
</div>
```

**dynamic-container.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-container',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-container.component.css']
})
export class DynamicContainerComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('container',{read:ViewContainerRef,static:true}) container:ViewContainerRef|any
  
  componentMap=new Map<string,ComponentRef<any>>()
  index=0

  productNames:any={
    mobile:'mobile',
    laptop:'laptop',
    watch:'watch',
    burger:'burger',
    ovan:'ovan'
  }
  createComponent(name:string){

    const compType=this.getComponentType(name)
    const comp=this.container.createComponent(compType) // comp store the reference returned by the method

    let uniqueName=name+' - '+this.index.toString()
    this.index++
    comp.instance.name=uniqueName // comp has a instance property
  }

  getComponentType(name:string):Type<any>
  {
    let type: Type<any>=MobileComponent
    
    switch(name)
    {
      case this.productNames.mobile:{
        type=MobileComponent
        break
      }
      case this.productNames.laptop:{
        type=LaptopComponent
        break
      }
      case this.productNames.burger:{
        type=BurgerComponent
        break
      }
      case this.productNames.ovan:{
        type=OvanComponent
        break
      }
      case this.productNames.watch:{
        type=WatchComponent
        break
      }
    }
    return type
  }
}
```

Below dynamic-container you can see there is a component called mobile(refer the image).

**In mobile.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mobile',
  templateUrl: './mobile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mobile.component.css']
})
export class MobileComponent {
  @Input() name:string=''
}
```

**In mobile.component.html**

```
<h4>{{name | titlecase}}</h4>
```

In case you want to see **app.component.html**

```
<app-dynamic-container></app-dynamic-container>
```

and **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DynamicContainerComponent,
        MobileComponent,
        LaptopComponent,
        BurgerComponent,
        WatchComponent,
        OvanComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports:[DynamicContainerComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I searched if there is any way of using @Input without property binding but found @Input need **[property binding]** and is done between parent and child component.

But you can see here it is done between 2 same level components that is **dynamic-container and mobile**.

So, I am not able to understand how it is happening under the hood or am I missing any concept. I found this in a youtube video here is the link - (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GE_lxrbFNtI&t=222s).
Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: Hope this helps [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

For passing data between same level component its better to use `services`. define your variables there and use it in both components.
otherwise if you don't want to use services, first you need to share data between the child to parent using `output` and `EventEmitter`. Once received data in parent component share it to another child component using `Input`.

Comment: I understand your point but can you tell me then how data is passed in the code code shown above?